# Ubuntu won't boot from hard drive

Tags: boot, partitioning

I decided to change my dual-boot Ubuntu/Windows 10 computer into a pure Ubuntu Mate computer. I edited the partition used for Ubuntu to add it back to Windows 10. When I next booted up my computer, it tried to boot Ubuntu, but went to Grub instead. I used f12 to open Windows and figured installing Ubuntu Mate would fix things, so I went on with my plan and installed it while erasing Windows. Now, whenever I boot up the computer, I can only do it from the flash drive, and it doesn't recognize I just installed Ubuntu Mate. In other words, my computer won't work unless I have a USB with an operating system installed. How can I fix this so it boots Ubuntu Mate from the Hard Drive?

Answer (score 0):

your question isn't so clear to me.
but from what i've understood the problem is about GRUB that doesn't recognize Ubuntu this can be solved using Ubuntu LiveCD/USB + Boot-Repair.
all what you need to do is to use you LiveCD to enter Ubuntu Graphical Mode the download and install Boot-Repair using the following commands:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair
boot-repair
```

then run boot-repair from unity-dash and try automatic repair it should make it run as good as it could be.
PS: you Ubuntu LiveCD version must be the exact version of Ubuntu installed on your machine.